# EF code first - List type property table name in db

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have roles and permissions classes in C#: `Permission` (that includes Roles list) and `Roles` (that includes Permissions list).

When I add new migration configuration, it creates `ROLE_PERMISSION` table in db, but I want `PERMISSION_ROLE` table.

I'm trying to add config like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>().Property(p => p.Roles).HasColumnName("PERMISSION_ROLE");
```

but I have error:

> The type 'ICollection' must be a non-nullable value type...

How can I configure some class's list-type property's name as table in db?

Thanks..

Comment: Look at this [article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx) on use of fluent api. It ha a section on column names. Without seeing the code around the above statement it is hard to know what the problem is.

Comment: Can you post your `DbContext` class  showing where the above code sits.

Comment: I can't show whole script, but there is one method that configures it using for cycle and Linq in db-context configuration script script.. I wanted to use Code-First functionality to do this..

Comment: I meant an extract of the key components of that method as shown in the example in the article I referenced.